# Is there a functor which is equivalent to discriminant of number field?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. The ring of integer $O_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Let $\{ a_1, \cdots , a_n\}$ be a integral basis of $O_K$. Then, 
$$
\Delta_{K/ \mathbb{Q}} = \det (\mathrm{Tr}(a_ia_j)_{i,j})
$$
is independent of choice of integral basis. We call $\Delta_{K/ \mathbb{Q}}$ a discriminant of number field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My question is:** Is there some categories $C,D$ and a functor $F \colon C \to D$ such that you have a simple way to get the discriminant $\Delta_{K/ \mathbb{Q}}$ from an object $F(K)$? I want $F$ to be a canonical one.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?  For what it's worth, the different ideal behaves nicely in a tower of number fields (if $K \subset L \subset M$ then $\mathcal D_{M/K} = \mathcal D_{M/L}\mathcal D_{L/K}$, where the second different on the right is meant to be extended to an ideal in the integers of $M$ to give meaning to that product of ideals) but the discriminant ideal does not (take ideal norms of both sides of that equation for different ideals and you'll see the discriminant ideal in towers satisfies a more complicated relation).

Comment: To complement the comment @KCd ,and interpreting this as 'is there any more genreal object useful in terms of the discriminant' you can associate to any map of rings (or schemes if you're algebraically minded) its module (sheaf) of differentials. The different that KCd mentioned is the annihilator of this module, and the discriminant is the norm of this annhilator.